# Insert in a newly created table in php returns 'Table table_name doesn't exist'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Completely lost. Basically, the script creates tables in mysql and populates them with holidays.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "wolla");
if ( !$link ) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

$createTablesQuery1 = "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;";
$createTablesQuery2 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `calendarCountries`;";
$createTablesQuery3 = "CREATE TABLE `calendarCountries` ( `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;";
$createTablesQuery4 = "insert into calendarCountries (id,country) values (1,'US');";
$createTablesQuery5 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `calendarWorldHolidays`;";
$createTablesQuery6 = "CREATE TABLE `calendarWorldHolidays` (`holidayName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,`holidayDate` date NOT NULL,`countryCode` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,KEY `countryCode` (`countryCode`),CONSTRAINT `calendarWorldHolidays_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`countryCode`) REFERENCES `calendarCountries` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;";
$createTablesQuery7 = "SET foreign_key_checks = 1;";

if ( !mysqli_multi_query( $link, $createTablesQuery1.$createTablesQuery2.$createTablesQuery3.$createTablesQuery4.$createTablesQuery5.$createTablesQuery6.$createTablesQuery7 ) )
    die( mysqli_error( $link ).'<br>');
    mysqli_close( $link );

    //INSERT HOLIDAYS INTO calendarWorldHolidays
    $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "wolla");
    mysqli_query( $link, "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;");
    $count = 0;
    $holidayCount = count( $holidayNames );
    while ( $count < $holidayCount ) {
        $insertHolidayQuery = 'Insert into calendarWorldHolidays (holidayName, holidayDate, countryCode) values ("'.$holidayNames[$count].'", '.$holidayDates[$count].'", 1)';
        if ( !mysqli_query( $link, $insertHolidayQuery ) ) {
        die(mysqli_error($link).'<br>');
        } else {
        $count++;
        }
    }
    mysqli_query( $link, "SET foreign_key_checks = 1;");
```

The Script the tables fine; however, when I try to do insert in a while loop, I get the following error

**Table 'wolla.calendarworldholidays' doesn't exist**
But the table does exist, because the code that creates it, executes fine, and when I check, I can see it in SQLPRO and phpmyadmin

The **$holidayNames** is an array of strings
The **$holidayDates** is an array of dates

And both of these have values inside

Please help, any advice on the matter is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right place? The error message you report doesn't seem to refer to the database you're using (`dbname` instead of `wolla`)

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I have edited wolla, changing it to dbname to make it more general. It is all wolla in my code, will edit the question, I am trying to find a bug somewhere with the quotations - i have changed quotes around trying ~ ' ", but that didnt help

Comment: `$insertHolidayQuery = "Insert into calendarWorldHolidays (holidayName, holidayDate, countryCode) values ('" .$holidayNames[$count]. "', '" .$holidayDates[$count]. "',1)";`

Comment: @undone, I have applied your suggested change. and got the following syntax error:  **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Day', '2013-01-21',1)' at line 1**  Does this mean that now php is able to find my table?

Comment: Can you try with `calendarWorldHolidays` in your insert query?

Comment: `$insertHolidayQuery = "Insert into calendarWorldHolidays (holidayName, holidayDate, countryCode) values ('" .
mysqli_real_escape_string($holidayNames[$count]). "', '" .mysqli_real_escape_string($holidayDates[$count]) . "',1)";`

Comment: And check if database exists. Have in mind in linux, table and database names are case-sensetive!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a syntax error with undone's solution is because

```
Insert into
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO
```

all caps

Comment: No, SQL keywords are case insensitive

Comment: Have you try with "INSERT" and "Insert"?